# LocalDate deserialization &serialization error -jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of java.time.LocalDate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jackson, spring-data-elasticsearch

The birthdate of the employee stored in the Elastic seems to be stored as an incorrect datatype. I have setup code for Elasticseach client with object mapper and registered JavaTime module. I am trying to pull employees list from Elasticsearch and it doesn't seem to work and is failing at deserializing.

```
Jar Versions:
org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client -> 6.4.3 (*)
org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client -> 6.4.3
org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch -> 6.4.3
org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch -> 3.1.4.RELEASE
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc -> 2.9.8
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8 (*)
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310 -> 2.9.8 (*)
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5 -> 2.9.8
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations -> 2.9.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner -> 2.9.8
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.9.8 (*)
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-modules-java8:2.9.8
```

Build.Gradle:

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner"
    runtime group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-modules-java8', version: '2.9.8', ext: 'pom'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-parameter-names
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-parameter-names', version: '2.9.8'

compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch'
    compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:transport'
    compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client'
    compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client'

    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch'
```

application.yml

```
jackson:
    serialization:
         WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
 jpa: 

    open-in-view: false
```

ElasticConfiguration Code:

```
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = { JacksonConfiguration.class })
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {



    RestHighLevelClient client = null; 

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient buildClient() {
        return new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(
                        new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                        new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate(final ElasticsearchConverter elasticsearchConverter,
            EntityMapper mapper, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder ) {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate((Client) buildClient(), new CustomEntityMapper(new ObjectMapper()));
    }
    //jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.createXmlMapper(false).build()


    public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        public CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
            objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
            objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
            //objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
            JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule=new JavaTimeModule();
            // Hack time module to allow 'Z' at the end of string (i.e. javascript json's) 
            javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
            javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
            objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
            objectMapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
            objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
            objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
        }

        @Override
        public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
            return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
        }
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to map source [ {"id":73,"name":"K****","birthDate":{"year":2019,"month":"MAY","dayOfYear":150,"leapYear":false,"dayOfMonth":30,"dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","era":"CE","monthValue":5,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}},"role..}] to class Employee
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractResultMapper.mapEntity(AbstractResultMapper.java:45) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.DefaultResultMapper.mapResults(DefaultResultMapper.java:102) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:315) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:309) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:139) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.findAll(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:126) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.findAll(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:120) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":73,"name":"Kelly","birthDate":{"year":2019,"month":"MAY","dayOfYear":150,"leapYear":false,"dayOfMonth":30,"dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","era":"CE","monthValue":5,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}},"role...}},"lastModifiedBy""[truncated 396 chars]; line: 1, column: 38] (through reference chain: Employee["birthDate"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1452) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1028) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.DefaultEntityMapper.mapToObject(DefaultEntityMapper.java:82) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractResultMapper.mapEntity(AbstractResultMapper.java:43) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Employee:

```
public class Employee extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    //Remaining Fields are removed for brevity
```

AbstractAuditEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class, EntityAuditEventListener.class})
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = true, length = 50, updatable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 50)
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem probably will be because Jackson does not support Java 8 DateTime Api out of the box.
So you can add the following library to add support for that (add in pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and configure object mapper to use this library module like :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
   .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
   .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
   .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Use the link for reference :
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

Comment: doesn't work. I have added jsr310 as shown above. And I added in the two new modules and it didn't work. Same error.

Comment: I have shared the code and added the changes above as well. Can you please be specific of what exactly you want to see?

Comment: Please verify that the birthDate value that you are trying to deserialize is in the (DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME) format as you have specified this in the deserializer.Also please share the Employee class and make sure you specified a uniform date format everywhere ,otherwise deserialization might not work properly.

Comment: done. I have added the code and I am only using LocalDate and LocalDateTime for entities fields.

Comment: `jackson-datatype-jsr310` is deprecated.

Comment: To clarify the statement by @cassiomolin above - the jackson-databind-jsr310 module project has been moved beneath  `jackson-modules-java8` repo: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8 - but the maven artifactId is otherwise unchanged and this answer remains correct.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully managed to use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) types in Spring Data Elasticsearch with the following configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "org.example.search.repository")
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(Client client) {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client, new CustomEntityMapper());
    }

    static class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

        private final ObjectMapper mapper;

        CustomEntityMapper() {
            mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                    .setDefaultPropertyInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
                    .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
                    .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                    .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
                    .findAndRegisterModules();
        }

        @Override
        public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
            return mapper.readValue(source, clazz);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share gradle/maven dependencies for jackson and elasticsearch? Are you using rest client?

Comment: I am running into same problem of using spring-data elastic with Java.time.instant class. I have used your configuration but still the same problem, please find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264654/spring-data-elastic-java-time-instant-class-jackson-deserliization-not-working/60265826#60265826 @cassiomolin could you please help me out

Answer (score 1):

It is more of a workaround but by adding the annotation mentioned below over the respective localdate/localdatetime fields.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a solution on version **ES-8** and **Spring Boot:3.0**

Create a configuration class extending `ElasticsearchConfiguration` and override clientConfiguration and elasticsearchClient creation.

During elasticsearchClient creation inject your own objectMapper configured to use Java 8 time module, which will override the default objectMapper.

```
@Override
public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
    return ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo(<Hostname> +":"+ <Port>)
            .usingSsl()
            .withBasicAuth(<Username>, <Password>)
            .build();
}


@Override
public ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient(RestClient restClient) {
    Assert.notNull(restClient, "restClient must not be null");

    //Create Java8 time module
    JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
    module.addSerializer(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DateFormat.date_time_no_millis.getPattern())));

    //Register the module with objectMapper
    ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(module);

    //To convert datetime to ISO-8601
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);


    //Creating our own jsonpMapper 
    JsonpMapper jsonpMapper=new JacksonJsonpMapper(objectMapper);

    // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
    ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
            restClient, jsonpMapper);

    // And create the API client
    return  new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
}
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```